# delphi function with Tcolor return

Tags: delphi, function, if-statement

just a quick one, busy with an assignment...
can someone just check if my logic is correct on this function because it does not seem to work, I dont get any errors when compiling

I call the function like this:

```
lblcolor.color :=  colorChooser(intVariable);
```

the function must make a label green, red, yellow or blue as in the code below, but it does not seem to work.

or do you guys think I must rather use a case statement for this one.

```
function ColorChooser(difference : integer): TColor;
begin
     if difference = 0 then
     begin
       Result := clGreen;
     end
     else if (difference >= 1) and (difference <= 3) then
     begin
        Result := clYellow;
     end
     else if (difference >= 4) 
          and (difference <= 8) then
     begin
        Result := clRed;
     end
     else
        Result := clBlue;

end;
```

Comment: What happens when you try to debug it?  Have you stepped through the code in the ide?

Comment: RAD XE3 - I ran the debugger but it just steps though it

Comment: You need more information, What doesn't work, what is returned from the function, which values of differnce give you values that work which ones give you values that don't.  If you want people to help you please at least give us sufficient information to try to solve your problem.

Comment: i gave the call the line of code... i gave the whole function...

Comment: Please can you format the code. That makes my eyes bleed.

Comment: the labels dont get colors after executing the code ie.. it does not work, what else do you need.

Comment: @David you beat me to that request, I was just typing it when I saw a new comment, and you read my mind :P

Comment: Unrelated... it's not necessary to have one line of code wrapped with `begin` and `end`, you can reduce your code size in half by removing them.

Comment: What is returned from the function?  Have you stepped through the function to see what it is returning.  Have you tried assigning  `lblcolor.color := clBlue; ` and see if that works, Is your function returning the correct value?  What have you tried????

Comment: Whilst you can reduce code size by removing begin end, you radically increase the chances of making the classic, else attached to wrong if mistake. Especially if you indent the code wrong.

Comment: thanks @Jerry ... the first positive comment

Comment: I see absolutely nothing wrong with your code which would cause this to not work. I think the problem is somewhere else, for example, are you using VCL Styles?

Comment: I would use [`this`](http://pastebin.com/bx0p4tZt).

Comment: @tlamam why not an answer?

Comment: okay @toby for some reason calling lblcolor.color := clBlue; just like that it also does not want to color my label.... strange...

Comment: @Peanut - You see my comments were positive.  That is basic debugging.

Comment: it was a transparency issue... thank you for all the help, im only a student now so I can only get better with all the help from you masters..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a major formatting issue here. :-) The problem is that the label takes on its parent's color by default, and is also transparent (meaning its background isn't visible). Set the label's `Transparent` property to `False` either in the Object Inspector at design time or in your `FormShow` event at runtime.

Now, let's clean up your code:

```
function ColorChooser(difference : integer): TColor;
begin
  Result := clBlue;
  if difference = 0 then
    Result := clGreen
  else if (difference >= 1) and (difference <= 3) then 
    Result := clYellow
  else if (difference >= 4) and (difference <= 8) then
    Result := clRed;
end;
```

To test it:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lblColor.Color := ColorChooser(Random(8));
end;
```

Now, a much cleaner way to write it:

```
function ColorChooser(difference : integer): TColor;
begin
  case difference of
    0: Result := clGreen;
    1..3: Result := clYellow;
    4..8: Result := clRed
  else
    Result := clBlue;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Assigning to `Color` forces `ParentColor` to be `False`.

Comment: +2 by the way for two different ways to write it :D

Comment: @David: Thanks. Fixed. (I don't set `Color` differently than the theme usually, so I'd forgotten that detail.)

Comment: Ken, you are going to have to work on the difference between it's (short for it is) and its (the possessive). That's two edits in one answer!  ;-)

Comment: @David: :-) I guess I will have to brush up. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the background color of a label. A control which is invariably transparent. So nothing happens.

Set `lbl.Font.Color` instead.

As for your function, a case statement is much cleaner:

```
case difference of
0:
  Result := clGreen;
1..3:
  Result := clYellow;
4..8:
  Result := clRed;
else
  Result := clBlue;
end;
```

If you really did want to set the background color, then you must set the label's `Transparent` property to `False`.

Comment: Or set `Transparent := False;`

Comment: @Peanut You really did want to set the background color?